# error: Can't resolve symbol 'AdRequest' and 'AdView'

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm trying to add a banner advertisement from AdMob.

```
dependencies {
        .......
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
    }
```

...

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Verified app-level build.gradle

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-MY_ID</string>
```

added my ad unit ID to strings.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

placed my ad to relative layout
also added `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to my relativelayout

In MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-MY_ID");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Eventhough, I've imported `import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;` still getting cannot resolve AdRequest and AdView errors.

I also tried clean project and download gradles again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved the issue

> go to **File > Project Structure > Dependencies**
>
> add google-play-services and google-play-ads

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File** > **Project Structure**> **Ads** > 
and enable the check box shown in Admob . 
click on **Ok** button
Its worked for me.........

Answer (score 1):

Change the version number of `play-services-ads` on your gradle to the same version number on your Ads setting page (File->Project Structure->Ads). By this way my android studio finally resolves `AdRequest` and `AdView`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

import this line above
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd